# Missing right parenthesis on CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: oracle, ddl

I'm getting an

> ORA-00907 error, missing right parenthesis

when attempting to create a table w MySQL.

I have looked extensively on the web but found nothing that could help me here..

Here is my CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE station
(
nomStation varchar2(255),
capacite number(15) NOT NULL,
lieu varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
region ENUM('Quebec', 'Ontario', 'NewBrunswick', 'NovaScotia'),
tarif number(10) DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT station_nomStation_pk PRIMARY KEY(nomStation)
);
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with both mysql AND oracle? Surely it can't be both!

Comment: I'm guessing he meant to type SQL and messed it up somehow.

Comment: Yes sorry it is Oracle. That is my first attempt at writing a statement as you can see..

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, "ORA-00907 error, missing right parenthesis" is usually triggered by a wrong number of commas, like adding an extra comma after your final column or constraint.

However, in your case some googling seems to indicate that Oracle doesn't support the ENUM syntax you're using. Instead, you should use a CHECK, like described in [this blog post](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.no/2005/05/enum-in-oracle.html).

Comment: Thanks Petter, it works. It seems I was reading both posts on MySQL and SQLplus at the same time. But that won't happen again now ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to upvote and/or check the answer as confirmed in case someone else makes a similar mistake.